# Downloading file from localhost site in PHP

Tags: php

When i am download a file with extention like mp3,flv etc it will now download it start buffering And when I remove extention from the file it downloads ...

can you please tell whats the problem behind that ...

file to download is => theangelfoundation-12-5-2012-09-17-27-somebody.mp3

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: because your browser has mediaplayer extensions, which buffers the media files recognized by the player. But if you remove extension or change extension to something else, it will ask you to download because the extension is not recognized by the mediaplayer extension in the browser

Comment: can you paste example code? Are you trying to just open a file in PHP and then output it to the browser?

Comment: can you give some code to understand?

Comment: Set the proper mime type in header indicating a dowload , then it will not buffer

Comment: @AkhilThayyil- can u tell how to set mime type in header

Comment: @gopalsharma : Mime type - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#107581

Answer (score 0):

```
 $file_types=array();

             $file_types['mp3']   ='audio/mpeg';
             $file_types['mpeg']  ='video/mpeg';
             $file_types['mpg']   ='video/mpeg';
             $file_types['pdf']   ='application/pdf';
             $file_types['pps']   ='application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
             $file_types['ppt']   ='application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
             $file_types['ps']    ='application/postscript';
             $file = 'you.mp3';  
             download($file,$file_types);    




function download($file_name,$file_types){

          $file = $file_name;
          $ext = end(explode('.',$file_name));
          if($ext && array_key_exists($ext,$file_types)){
          if (file_exists($file)) {
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
             header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
             header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
             header('Expires: 0');
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
             header('Pragma: public');
             header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
             ob_clean();
             flush();
             readfile($file);
             exit;
             }
          }
         else {
            die("this is not a downloadable file");
             }




        }


?>
<a href="force_download.php?file=ok.txt"> download ok.txt</a>
```